# Network Adapter occasionally not able to connect

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

Sometimes my network adapter will require that I disable it and then reenable in order for it to work again. The problem  is that it gives no indication that there is a problem with the network until I try to access the web (The icon says it is connected, even though it is obviously not). It seems to randomly happen on times when I log in, after being in hibernate mode. Other than that, it works fine afterwords. Until it does happen again, and I have to go back and disable and reenable the driver. So what is the problem here? Is the network card or the driver, or something else? And yes, my driver is up to date and I don't have any viruses. My operating system is Windows 8.1.

Comment: In Device Manager find your network adapter, right-click it and select Properties, go to the Power Management tab and clear the setting to *Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power*. See if that helps.

Comment: I did what you said. Hope this works. I will need to wait for a while and see it it happens again.